# Displaying thumbnails with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, thumbnails

Can someone help me display thumbnails of images as they are being uploaded? A link or some quick pseudo code will help a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just put this code in your html page: **<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>**